# nbViewer will not display content from The Littlest Jupyter Hub

Tags: jupyterhub, nbconvert, nbviewer

TLJH is running and I can access a file

```
http://localhost/user/myUser/notebooks/Label%20reader/single_file_code.py.ipynb
```

nbviewer is running, I have started it with

```
python3 -m nbviewer --debug --no-cache --host=127.0.0.1 --base-url=http://localhost/user --no-check-certificate
```

Attempting to use nbviewer to display the file

```
localhost:5000/url/myUser/notebooks/Label reader/label_reader part 1.ipynb
```

generates a 404 : Not found error

I have also installed nbviewer via the docker image and I get a similar result. In that case

```
http://localhost:8080/url/localhost/user/myUser/notebooks/Label%20reader/label_reader%20part%201.ipynb
```

resulted in

```
400 : Bad Request
Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

TLJH is definitely running on port 80

Comment: Well that one `localhost:5000/url/myUser/notebooks/Label reader/label_reader part 1.ipynb` looks like an obvious issue of using spaces in file names and thus making a bad command. Simplify your file names and paths and see if that helps. Are you able to look in the log, like referenced [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/918#issue-600571800) and see where nbviewer is trying to reach the file. Did you set the hub to use localfiles as referenced [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/991)?